# How to fix File is empty.?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload an image to my Wordpress site but I am getting the following error message:

> File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

Please help me.

Screen shot:

[image: image upload error]

Comment: are you trying this on any server or on your localhost

Comment: Hello Amanjot, Running on GoDaddy server

Answer (score 1):

I landed here searching for this solution but found my own.

I had to change the following:

`post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize`

To sizes larger than my import file size in cPanel under MultiPHP INI Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file that is available inside php folder of web server app like xampp. Then edit this file and check two settings: post_max_size and upload_max_filesize.
Check if these settings fits your uploaded file size to upload it. After editing, you can restart web server app and try again.

Comment: php.ini also checked but now same error coming. It is running on godaddy server. Where to locate php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we need to set permissions for the file upload on server.

https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-windows-6481

Answer (score 0):

PHP stores uploads in a temporary location before moving them to their ultimate destination. In your php.ini file, check the value of `upload_tmp_dir`

If it is not writeable by the Wordpress process, you'll get an indication of a zero-byte upload (and the "substantial" message.)

To help debug this, I've (temporarily) added a print_r($file) line to wp-admin/includes/file.php  (look for the  `if ( $test_size && ! ( $test_file_size > 0 ) )`  test).  When uploading a file, this will indicate what PHP thinks it is getting, and a clue as to where it may be failing.

In our case, we had just applied a set of security patches to our Debian server. In php.ini, the "upload_tmp_dir" directive was commented-out, so PHP was using the system default temp. directory.  After the server updates, this directory was no longer writeable by Wordpress. Uncommenting upload_tmp_dir and changing it to /var/tmp fixed the problem:

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
upload_tmp_dir = /var/tmp
```